# Cherubim gender differences

Tags: ark-aron-kodesh, cherubim, gender

While I have found two different versions of Cherubim's gender:

- they were both males (the Torah says איש אל אחיו, implying two of them were male), also other commentators in place
- they were male and female ([Yumah 54a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.54a.18?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he))

In any case, was their gender visually apparent or were there no physical signs of gender?

Comment: re 1st version: Exodus 26:17?

Comment: @Liberian sorry, I don't understand please elaborate

Comment: I strongly suspect "איש אל אחיו" can mean only that the antecedent word is masculine, even if the referent of that word is not male.

Comment: @msh210 איש means masculine - agreed? אחיו means masculine - agreed (compare to אישה את אחותה)? It could read איש אל אחותו or אישה אל אחיה. In Hebrew, אחיו cannot stand for feminine.

Comment: Where is this Gemara in Yoma?

Comment: @AlBerko But כרוב is masculine. The אשה אל אחותה that you mention is used about inanimate objects that are grammatically feminine

Comment: @DonielF 54a/b https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.54a.18?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he

Comment: @AlBerko That doesn’t say that they were male and female. It says that they were embracing one another the way a man would his wife.

Comment: The Gemora you refer to is talking about the 2nd temple - and there were no Cherubs there - rather it's referring to the engravings on the wall as per Rashi.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that there are various opinions as to what they looked like, from birds to human-like to birds with human faces.

It would seem that if they were of both genders it would be apparent in their facial features.

Some related sources:

<sup>(In the order that Sefaria brings them.)</sup>
The [Ksav VeHakabolo](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.25.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=HaKtav_VeHaKabalah%2C_Exodus.25.18.1&lang2=he) says one was male and the other female, but he doesn't elaborate:

> **שנים כרובים.** לא אמר שני, בעבור כי שני לשון השווי', כמו שני לוחות העדות, שני כבשים, שני השעירים, וכאן הוצרך לומר שנים כי חלוקים הם בענינם, **זה זכר וזה נקבה**, וחזר ואמר מבין שני הכרבים, ויעש שני כרבים, לרמוז על השויתם בזהב ובאחדות (רב"ח). עתי"ט נגעים פי"ד מ"ה:‏

It's unclear to me why he refers to the [תי"ט נגעים פי"ד מ"ה](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Negaim.14.5?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Mishnah_Negaim.14.5.1&lang2=bi) as that seems to contradict his opinions. I.e. since the Torah repeated itself, they should be identical-looking.

I assume he means this section:

> **מצותן שיהיו שוות במראה ובקומה וכו'.** פי' הר"ב דלכתוב רחמנא צפרים כו'. שתי דכתב רחמנא למה לי כו'. וקשיא לי דברפ"ו דיומא בשני שעירי יה"כ דתנן התם נמי כה"ג ופי' הר"ב דתלתא קראי כתיבי ואילו הכא הא ליכא אלא חד קרא ומיהו לא על הר"ב תלונותינו. דדבריו דהתם ודהכא. גמ' ערוך הן שם ביומא. ונ"ל דמדגלי לן רחמנא [ח] גבי שני שעירים דלכל הני בעינן שיהיו שוות. כי כתב גבי צפרים חד זימנא שתי. לאגמרינן שיהיו שוות. לא צריך לתלתא קראי. דנשמעיני' מהגלוי דגלי לן גבי שני שעירים דלכולן יהיו שוות: ‏

The [HaEmek Dover](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.25.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Haamek_Davar_on_Exodus.25.18.1&lang2=he) mentions the Gemora you bring, without mentioning that this was in the 2nd temple where there were no Cheruvim. Perplexing.

The [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.25.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Chizkuni%2C_Exodus.25.18.1&lang2=he) says that they were bird-like. That would infer that there was no visible difference.

> שנים כרבים ד**וגמא מין של עוף** כדכתיב ביחזקאל את כרוב ממשח הסוכך, פירש עוף גדול בעל כנפים‏

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.25.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Malbim_on_Exodus.25.18.1&lang2=he) says that they were visibly different, but doesn't elaborate.

> **ועשית שנים כרובים.** מבואר אצלי (באילת השחר כלל ס"ז) שיש הבדל בין שנים ובין שני, ששני מורה על השווי, **ושנים מורה שאינם שוים,** ומזה הוכיחו חז"ל שהיו בדמות זכר ונקבה והיו בלתי שוים.‏

[Rabbeinu Bachya](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.25.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Shemot.25.18.5&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he) takes both approaches - first saying they were male & female as per the Gemora in Yuma, and then saying that possibly the only difference was that one had a younger-looking face and the other had older features.

> והיה אפשר שהיו הכרובים **האחד כצורת אדם גדול והשני כצורת ילד קטן** כענין שראה יחזקאל פני האחד פני הכרוב ופני השני פני אדם, ודרשו רז"ל היינו כרוב היינו אדם אלא אפי רברבי ואפי זוטרי, ויהיה זה להעיד על אהבתו לישראל כאהבת האב לבנו שהיא אהבה חזקה

[Rashbam](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.25.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashbam_on_Exodus.25.18.1&lang2=he) says they were birds with human faces.

> **כרבים - עופות**, כדכתיב: (יחזקאל כח) את כרוב ממשח הסוכך. עוף גדול בעל כנפים. וחכמים פירשו: **פני תינוק**.‏

Comment: I don't see that opinion in the Rashbam you brought, but a good answer nevertheless, +1